# Заставить PureComponent обновляться при setState с тем же объектом

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В следующем примере при нажатии кнопки `no` компонент не перерисовывается (хотя значение в state'е меняется). Понятно, что это происходит из-за того, что ссылка на объект `obj` не меняется, а `PureComponent` перерисовывается только при верхнеуровневом изменении значений. Что можно сделать, чтобы компонент перерисовался, если отказаться от внутреннего изменения невозможно?

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    obj: { x: 10 }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.state.obj.x}{" "}
        <button onClick={this.no}>no</button>{" "}
        <button onClick={this.ok}>ok</button>
      </p>
    )
  }
  
  no = () => {
    var { obj } = this.state
    ++obj.x
    this.setState({ obj })
  }
  
  ok = () => {
    var { obj } = this.state
    obj = { ...obj, x: obj.x+1 }
    this.setState({ obj })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменение чего-то внутри `state` является антипаттерном, но если по какой-то причине от этого нельзя избавиться, то можно вместо `setState` стоит использовать `forceUpdate`:

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    obj: { x: 10 }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.state.obj.x}{" "}
        <button onClick={this.no}>no</button>{" "}
        <button onClick={this.ok}>ok</button>
      </p>
    )
  }
  
  no = () => {
    var { obj } = this.state
    ++obj.x
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
  
  ok = () => {
    var { obj } = this.state
    obj = { ...obj, x: obj.x+1 }
    this.setState({ obj })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Если неизвестно, будет ли возвращённый объект `obj` новым или изменённым старым, можно использовать коллбек, вызываемый после изменения state, однако стоит понимать, что это потенциально может вызвать двойную перерисовку, так что я так делать не советую без очень крайней необходимости:

```
this.setState({ obj }, () => this.forceUpdate())
```

А ещё стоит рассотреть вариант отказа от PureComponent - тогда обновление будет происходить на каждый вызов setState (но ещё и на каждый рендеринг родителя, так что может ухудшиться производительность):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    obj: { x: 10 }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.state.obj.x}{" "}
        <button onClick={this.no}>no</button>{" "}
        <button onClick={this.ok}>ok</button>
      </p>
    )
  }
  
  no = () => {
    var { obj } = this.state
    ++obj.x
    this.setState({ obj })
  }
  
  ok = () => {
    var { obj } = this.state
    obj = { ...obj, x: obj.x+1 }
    this.setState({ obj })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

И даже для `PureComponent` можно сделать метод `shouldComponentUpdate`, определяющий, надо ли компоненту обновляться, хотя реакт вполне справедливо кинет на это предупреждение о том, что так поступать не стоит - зачем писать PureComponent, если его функциональность полностью переопределяется?